# Adding saml token to wso2 php request

Tags: php, web-services, wso2, saml, wso2-esb

I would like to add a SAML token to a service request using WSO2 php. In our system we have an STS service, responsible for authentication users based on username and password. The service then responds with a SAML assertion, to be used for calling other services. I've looked at the samples for wso2 php, and getting the saml token should be okay. But struggling to see how I should add it to the WSSecurityToken object. Can it be done in a proper way, or would one need to construct the xml payload and inject the SAML assertion into the header.

For our java clients I use apache axis/rampart

Thanks, Håkon